# React Native WebView is not working on some devices

Tags: android, react-native, webview

Hy guys, I'm using react native cli. I'm using the webview.
`import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';`

```
  <WebView
                 ref={webViewRef}
                source={{uri:uri}}
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                onNavigationStateChange={
                  (state)=>{
                    const back = state.canGoBack
                    const forward = state.canGoForward
                    setCanGoBack(back)
                    setCanGoForward(forward)
                  } 
               }
              />
```

Its working on some devices very perfectly but on some of old devices it displaying me this error:

```
Error Loading Page 
Domain Undefined 
Error Code: 3
Description SSL error: The certificate authority is not trusted
```

Does someone have an idea what's the problem there? I try to search error code 3 webview but can't get things to solve.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: no @JeafGilbert

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `usesCleartextTraffic` in `project/android/src/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

More details [Here](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1050)

Comment: its already added.

Comment: any comment for ios?